# How to test/debug parameterised SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, prepared-statement, informix

My code (java in this case, but it doesn't matter) executes complex SQL statements against a database. These SQLs are parameterised, with up to 50 parameters in some cases.  They are very complex, often longer than a page of printed paper, joining dozens of tables, subselects, conditional case-when and so on.

The code looks something like this:

```
final String sql = "SELECT ...";
PreparedStatement stmt = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

sql.setString(1, ...);
sql.setInt(2, ...);
sql.setDate(3, ...);
...
sql.setString(50, ...);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

As the sql statements are parameterised, I can't just copy/paste the SQL statement into a database console to test/debug the statement, since all the "?" in it will cause errors.

When I get incorrect results or syntax errors, I need to be able to debug them somehow - but how?  How can I run this monstrosity in a database console to be able to play with parameters and/or get more specific syntax errors than just "syntax error near '('"?

I have code that runs against MS SQL Server (version 2014 - not in a position to upgrade) and Informix (version 7.3 - again, not in a position to upgrade).  Even one of them would be helpful, although SQL Server is the priority for me.

Note, I am *not* in at liberty to rewrite the code to run multiple smaller queries instead of the large ones. Please do not suggest rewriting them - this is not what the question is about.

Comment: Have you looked at [sp_blitzcache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/). After clearing the proc cache you can run your prepared statement and grab the compile-time parameter values and SQL statement, makes it somewhat easier to build a testable query.

Comment: @Stu I have the compiled statement and all the parameter values - but how to do I run it?  If it were 1 or 2 parameters, I would manually edit them in, replacing the ?, but I have 40-50 parameters

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint  in the code at `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();` and look at the value of String `sql` in the debugger, copy it, and paste that into the DB console?

Comment: @HardCode Yes I can, but that does not help.  The parameter substitution is not done in the code.  The code sends the SQL statement with all the "?" and separately the parameter list to the server - and the SQL Server does the parameter substitution

Comment: @AleksG Perhaps you can run the query from your code, while at the same time going to MS SQL Server, viewing Activity Monitor, and grab your statement as it's running. You should be able to see the complete SQL statement (`Activity Monitor --> Processes` filter by DB, find your running statement, right-click, select `Details`).

Comment: @HardCode that might help in some cases, specifically where the query compiles successfully and takes some time to run.  It won't help with debugging syntax errors; it also isn't going to be easy for queries that run very quickly, under 1 second, which is the case with quite a few of mine.

Comment: It may be possible using extended events, although I can't comment on SQL Server 2014. [see this as an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-iDdB18uJ8)

Comment: Seems like you're trying to test everything at once. Why not break the problem up? Put the SQL code into stored procedures that you can unit test separately from Java using tSQLt. Then write JUnit/whatever tests that properly mock the Connection interface to confirm that the correct parameters are being set from application code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks, but I think you may be missing the point. I need to test that the correct sql is executed against the database - I need to send the sql to the actual database to confirm that it's correct.